# S3 bucket access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to give single  S3 bucket access to different user without listing all the buckets, Hence I didnot use list all my buckets policy. The buckets contains different folders inside folders, when I am trying to list the contents in the folder through its shows nothing

The policy I am using

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::abcd”
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::abcd”
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AddDeleteFiles",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::abcd”
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::abcd/*”
        }
    ]

}
```

output of s3cmd ls [s3://abcd/aa] -acess denied

Comment: See http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1P2T3LFXXCNB5/Writing-IAM-policies-Grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-Amazon-S3-bucke.

Comment: I have more than 10 folders inside and each folders has sub and sub folders, The s3 path mainly will be like this s3://abcd/aa/bb/date/00/fb/xvz.gz file, and there so many .gz files in fb, I think I cannot able to access all of them

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your s3cmd with the right aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key ?

```
s3cmd --configure
```

basically creates a ~/.s3cfg command with the right parameters.

Also on Principal you need to specify your account id. For example:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddCannedAcl",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": {"AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root","arn:aws:iam::444455556666:root"]},
      "Action":["s3:PutObject","s3:PutObjectAcl"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"],
      "Condition":{"StringEquals":{"s3:x-amz-acl":["public-read"]}}
    }
  ]
}
```

You'll have to make sure what your are putting in a bucket policy or IAM policy, as they are not interchangeable. You can have both but you have to make sure each one is the correct for the type of policy

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ya the details are correct,basically I am using s3cmd ls s3://abcd/aa it opening as DIR s3://abcd/aa/

Comment: abcd is bucket name , aa is the folder in the bucket

Comment: @cvasired how about the Principal and account id ? check my edits

Comment: hey, this policy is for iam user , what do u mean by principal and account ids, please explain

Comment: you have             "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::abcd”
            },  in your policy.. you don't need that if it's IAM policy

Comment: I have added the policy u mentioned it still shows the same output while using s3cmd

Comment: @cvasired you'll have to make sure what your are putting in a bucket policy or IAM policy, as they are not interchangeable. You can have both but you have to make sure each one is the correct for the type of policy

Comment: I am using the above mentioned policy as a bucket policy. Even the updated one, if wrong, Please suggest